# How to get value of ReactBootstrapSlider?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I am using ReactBootstrapSlider component in my project. I just want to get the currentValue of the slider. When slider stops i want to get its value and save this value to the redux store.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that your slider component looks like

```
<ReactBootstrapSlider
   value={this.state.currentValue}
   step={100}
   change={this.changeValue}
   slideStop={this.changeValue}
   max={10000}
   min={0}
   orientation="horizontal"
   reverse={true}
/>
```

Then you can simply get its value by implementing the below function.

```
 changeValue(event){
     console.log("Current Value is " , event.target.value);}
```

*event.target.value* will give you the Slider's value.